# On Click só funciona uma vez

Tags: jquery, onclick

Tenho o seguinte código para mostrar e esconder conteúdo, mas só funciona uma vez. Quando clico novamente para esconder, nada acontece.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li[name=music]').off().on('click', function() {
        if ($(this).children().css('display', 'none')) {
            $(this).children().css('display', 'block');
        } else {
            $(this).children().css('display', 'none');
        };
    });
});
```

http://codepen.io/evemontalvao/pen/PZPpgM

Comment: showMusic() não esta definido, onde você declarou ela ?

Answer (score 2):

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

        function mostra() {
            if (document.getElementById('teste').style.display == 'block'){
                document.getElementById('teste').style.display = 'none';
            }else {document.getElementById('teste').style.display = 'block'}
        }

    </script>
```

Em 'teste' voce coloca o id da sua div , e no botao coloca :

```
onclick="mostra('teste')"
```

Answer (score 2):

Analisando o seu código HTML, você pode simplesmente fazer:

```
$('li[name=music]').on('click', function () {
  $el = $(this).children('div');
  /*
  * Desta forma vc verifica se a div está visível
  * ao invés de if($(this).children().css('display','none'))
  * que sempre retornará verdadeiro
  */
  if($el.is(':visible')){ 
    $el.css('display','none');
  } else {
    $el.css('display','block');
  }
});
```

Outra sugestão, aproveitando que você está utilizando o framework Bootstrap, você pode colocar a classe `hide` na `div` e utilizar a função `toggleClass`, exemplo:

```
$('li[name=music]').on('click', function () {
  $(this).children('div').toggleClass('hide');
});
```

Outra dica seria trocar ID por Classes no CSS `#music1, #music2, #music3` por `.music`.

**[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PZPMyL)**

Comment: Só não esquece de explicar o erro no código do AP (sobre o `if($(this).children().css('display','none')){`). +1

Answer (score 0):

Pra que isso tudo?  use [toggle()!](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

```js
$('li[name=music]').click(function() {
  $(this).find('div').toggle();
});
```

```css
#music1,
#music2,
#music3 {
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1%;
  text-transform: none;
  color: #bb5d6a;
}
ul.nav-pills li {
  background-color: #faf7ea;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
ul.nav-pills li a {
  color: #bb5d6a;
  font-family: 'Pathway Gothic One', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
.icon::before {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: .5em;
  font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
  font-size: inherit;
  text-rendering: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
    <li role="presentation" name="music"><a class="icon fa-play-circle-o" href="#musicas"> Lorem Ipsum</a>
      <div id="music1" name="mostra">

        teste
      </div>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" name="music"><a class="icon fa-play-circle-o" href="#musicas"> Lorem Ipsum</a>
      <div id="music2">

        teste
      </div>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" name="music"><a class="icon fa-play-circle-o" href="#musicas"> Lorem Ipsum</a>
      <div id="music3">
        teste
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

o `toggle` não seria suficiente?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('li[name=music]').off().on('click', function () {
        $(this).toggle();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nesta linha `if ($(this).children().css('display', 'none')) {` essa verificação vai sempre dar verdadeiro. Isso porque esse método do jQuery retorna o próprio objeto, e objetos quando convertidos em booleanos dão `true`.

Nesse `if` deverias ter somente `$(this).children().css('display')` vai dar uma string, e depois comparar com `block` por exemplo...

Se o que pretendes é esconder e mostrar os elementos descendentes podes simplificar o código. Podes misturar CSS nisso que é melhor.

Algo assim:

CSS

```
.esconde > * {
  display: none;
}
```

JavaScript

```
$('li[name=music]').on('click', function () {
  this.classList.toggle('esconde');
});
```

#### exemplo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VevoOG

Answer (score 0):

Tente:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('li[name=music] a').on('click', function () {
    $(this).next().toggle(); 
  });
});
```